# Can we get the publishing history of a Tridion component?

Tags: publishing, 2013, processhistory

We have an issue with a component in which in-appropriate content was published and then unpublished.

From the publishing queue we were able to get only the last publish transaction of that component.

Is there any way to retrieve the complete publishing history of that component?

Would like to know who and when was this published and how many times it was published and unpublished.

Also ,our normal modification history was deleted to find out the modifications.

Please let us know a way to figure this out.

Thanks,

Sampath

Comment: i heard that from 2013 or 2013SP1 the history is stored in the DB and it is possible to retrieve via API but is not exposed in the GUI.  Previous versions could implement an Event System or custom Deployer to write every instance of publishing to an external storage system...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not a way, out of the box, to see all publish history. By default only the last published date is available.

You could trawl the deployer log files for the publish transaction, but that would not tell you who published it.

If you require this functionality / audit trail, you would have to implement Tridion Events system and record each publish to a database or log file. You could then run reports on this to determine the required information.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this is an unsupported low level way to get a list of published transactions (user name, publish time, publication target, path of the page, ) for any given item

```
select top 1000 t.name, pt.publish_time, pta.TITLE, pt.source_item_path 
from publish_transactions pt, trustees t, publication_targets pta
where pt.SOURCE_ITEM_REFERENCE_ID = 7386 and pt.trustee_id=t.id and pt.PUBLICATION_TARGET_ID=pta.ID
```

Comment: This only brings you the latest time it has been published to each target, not all publishing history for the item.